Is it normal for Power Statistics to report designed battery capacity as less than what the manufacturer advertised?
I bought a laptop with an advertised 38 Wh battery. When I go to Power Statistics, it tells me that "Energy When Full" and "Energy (Design)" are both 30.4 Wh.
Does this mean the manufacturer lied in their ad? Or is it normal for these numbers to be somewhat different from advertised? (What does your laptop say?)
At least that looks like the battery health is 100% since Energy When Full is the same as Energy (Design). Unless, maybe it means the battery is unable to correctly report Energy (Design) and just reports the Energy When Full number instead for both. So could it be possible that the battery's design energy is actually 38 Wh but battery health is only 80% (= 30.4 / 38) ?
The fact that 30.4 is exactly 80% of the advertised capacity looks odd to me. Perhaps there is some other explanation. Like maybe the battery is somehow configured in the firmware (not by me) to only charge up to 80% of maximum for better long-term health, and that's what it is reporting as the maximum even though the actual maximum would be higher.

this has nothing to do with the OS. The OS only reports what it has been told by the BIOS. You need to ask bios and/or hardware experts.
